# Invalid attempt to destruction non-iterable instance with useState for conditional rendering

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, use-state

Been banging on this for about 4 hours, literally. I keep getting the error:

```
Invalid attempt to destructure non-iterable instance. In order to be iterable, non-array objects must have a [Symbol.iterator]() method.
```

I am trying to conditionally render components based on whether or not a user is logged in. Here is my code

```
const App = () => {
  const [isLoggedIn, setIsLoggedIn] = React.useState(false);
  const AppBody = () => {
    return (
      <NavigationContainer>
        <Stack.Navigator>
          {isLoggedIn ? (
            <Stack.Screen
              name="Initiation"
              component={Initiation}
              options={{headerShown: false}}
            />
          ) : (
            <>
              <Stack.Screen
                name="Activities"
                component={Activities}
                options={{headerShown: false}}
              />
              <Stack.Screen
                name="Messages"
                component={Messages}
                options={{headerShown: false}}
              />
              <Stack.Screen
                name="Persona"
                component={Persona}
                options={{headerShown: false}}
              />
            </>
          )}
        </Stack.Navigator>
      </NavigationContainer>
    );
  };

  React.useEffect(() => {
    AppBody();
  }, [isLoggedIn]);

  return <AppBody />;
};

export default App;
```

This logic was rendering fine until today when I started getting the error above. I have tried several different solutions, including returning the conditional logic straight in App.js body instead of the AppBody.js body, and I have also tried reordering the code several times over.

At this point, I know I am missing something in plain sight. I am just at a loss for what it is.

**EXTRA**

xCode 12.4

React-Native 0.63

**ERROR STACK**

```
This error is located at:
    in Activities (at SceneView.tsx:122)
    in StaticContainer
    in StaticContainer (at SceneView.tsx:115)
    in EnsureSingleNavigator (at SceneView.tsx:114)
    in SceneView (at useDescriptors.tsx:153)
    in RCTView (at View.js:34)
    in View (at CardContainer.tsx:245)
    in RCTView (at View.js:34)
    in View (at CardContainer.tsx:244)
    in RCTView (at View.js:34)
    in View (at CardSheet.tsx:33)
    in ForwardRef(CardSheet) (at Card.tsx:573)
    in RCTView (at View.js:34)
    in View (at createAnimatedComponent.js:165)
    in AnimatedComponent (at createAnimatedComponent.js:215)
    in ForwardRef(AnimatedComponentWrapper) (at Card.tsx:555)
    in PanGestureHandler (at GestureHandlerNative.tsx:13)
    in PanGestureHandler (at Card.tsx:549)
    in RCTView (at View.js:34)
    in View (at createAnimatedComponent.js:165)
    in AnimatedComponent (at createAnimatedComponent.js:215)
    in ForwardRef(AnimatedComponentWrapper) (at Card.tsx:544)
    in RCTView (at View.js:34)
    in View (at Card.tsx:538)
    in Card (at CardContainer.tsx:206)
    in CardContainer (at CardStack.tsx:620)
    in RCTView (at View.js:34)
    in View (at Screens.tsx:84)
    in MaybeScreen (at CardStack.tsx:613)
    in RCTView (at View.js:34)
    in View (at Screens.tsx:54)
    in MaybeScreenContainer (at CardStack.tsx:495)
    in CardStack (at StackView.tsx:462)
    in KeyboardManager (at StackView.tsx:458)
    in RNCSafeAreaProvider (at SafeAreaContext.tsx:74)
    in SafeAreaProvider (at SafeAreaProviderCompat.tsx:42)
    in SafeAreaProviderCompat (at StackView.tsx:455)
    in RCTView (at View.js:34)
    in View (at StackView.tsx:454)
    in StackView (at createStackNavigator.tsx:87)
    in StackNavigator (at App.js:24)
    in EnsureSingleNavigator (at BaseNavigationContainer.tsx:409)
    in ForwardRef(BaseNavigationContainer) (at NavigationContainer.tsx:91)
    in ThemeProvider (at NavigationContainer.tsx:90)
    in ForwardRef(NavigationContainer) (at App.js:23)
    in AppBody (at App.js:59)
    in App (at renderApplication.js:45)
    in RCTView (at View.js:34)
    in View (at AppContainer.js:106)
    in RCTView (at View.js:34)
    in View (at AppContainer.js:132)
    in AppContainer (at renderApplication.js:39)
```

Answer (score 0):

The error was in my activities file. I had an object I was destructuring that looked like:

```
const [var1, var2] = {
    key: value
};
```

I stupidly left this code unfinished and did not know it was causing the error because I did not read the error stack. I spent 4 hours tweaking the wrong file. Lesson - always read the error stack.

Comment: Ohhhhh, I hate when that happens :-( Sorry for your trouble.

Answer (score -1):

The error you are mentioning is not happening in this component, could you please paste the error stack?